# nested FormGroup angular5 not working

Tags: angular

I am using nested form group in angular6 app.

```
 export class NestedFormComponent implements OnInit {

  myForm: FormGroup

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    const phone = this.fb.group({
      area: [],
      prefix: [],
      line: []
    });

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      email: '',
      homePhone: phone,
      cellPhone: phone
    });

    this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(console.log)
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}

<div id="formContainer">
```

```
<div>{{myForm.value | json}}</div>
<hr />

<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
  <input matInput placeholder="email" formControlName='email'>
</mat-form-field>

<h4>Cell Phone</h4>
<div formGroupName='cellPhone'>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" plcaeholder='area' matInput formControlName='area'>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="prefix" matInput formControlName='prefix'>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="line" matInput formControlName='line'>
  </mat-form-field>

</div>

<h4>Home Phone</h4>
<div formGroupName='homePhone'>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" plcaeholder='area' matInput formControlName='area'>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="prefix" matInput formControlName='prefix'>
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field>
    <input type="text" placeholder="line" matInput formControlName='line'>
  </mat-form-field>

</div>
```

Whenever i change value in any form-group, it is getting updated in another. Please help.

slackblitz is [slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kjyqse?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using the same fb.group instance via the phone constant:

This should work :

```
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 

    this.myForm = this.fb.group({
      email: '',
      homePhone: this.createFormGroup(),
      cellPhone: this.createFormGroup()
    })
  }

  createFormGroup() {
    return this.fb.group({
      area: [],
      prefix: [],
      line: []
    });
  }
```

I've updated your [slackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qpb6xu?file=src/nested-form/nested-form.component.ts)